# androidx.paging.PagedListAdapter' is deprecated

Tags: android, androidx, android-paging, android-paging-library

I'm using an alpha release of androidx's paging library in my android project. It used to work fine but today my android studio started to show this deprecation warning about the **PagedListAdapter** class. I searched on google and also checked out the official documentation on the android developer's website, but didn't find anything.

I'm using the following dependency:

```
def paging_version = "3.0.0-alpha06"
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:$paging_version" //pagination
```

Ataching screenshot for reference: [image: Ataching screenshot for reference]

It is just an android studio's glitch or it has been really deprecated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PagedListAdapter` has been deprecated in favor of `PagingDataAdapter`. Paging3 is essentially a full rewrite of Paging2, but in kotlin + coroutines. You can find docs here: [d.android.com/paging3](http://d.android.com/paging3) as well as a link to the codelab and samples.